# "async with" within asyncio.Task not working

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am learning python `asyncio` and testing a lot of code using them.
Below is a code where I try to subscribe multiple *Websocket* streaming using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`.

**I do not understand why when `coro(item1, item2):` is executed as a task, it does not go into the `async with ...` block. (i.e "A" is printed but not "B").**
Could anyone help me understand the reason for this?

(I have already got a [working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032901/multiple-websocket-streaming-with-asyncio-aiohttp/68033026?noredirect=1#comment120248389_68033026) but , I simply want to understand what the mechanism behind this is.)

#### Code

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json

async def coro(
               item1,
               item2):
    print("A")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.ws_connect(url='URL') as ws:
            print("B")

            await asyncio.gather(ws.send_json(item1),
                                 ws.send_json(item2))
            print("C")

            async for msg in ws:
                print(msg)

async def ws_connect(item1,
                     item2):
    task = asyncio.create_task(coro(item1, item2))
    return task

async def main():

    item1 = {
        "method": "subscribe",
        "params": {'channel': "..."}
    }
    item2 = {
        "method": "subscribe",
        "params": {'channel': "..."}
    }

    ws_task = await ws_connect(item1, item2)
    print("D")

asyncio.run(main())
```

#### Output

```
D
A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*B* is never printed because you never await the returned task, only the method which returned it.

The subtle mistake is in `return task` followed by `await ws_connect(item1, item2)`.

**TL;DR;** `return await task`.

The key to understand the program's output is to know that the context switches in the asyncio event loop can only occur at few places, in particular at `await` expressions. At this point, the event loop *might* suspend the current coroutine and continue with another.

First, you create a `ws_connect` coroutine and immedietely await it, this forces the event loop to suspend `main` and actually run `ws_connect` because there is not anything else to run.

Since `ws_connect` contains none of those points which allow context switch, the `coro()` function never actually starts.

Only thing `create_task` does is binding the coroutine to the task object and adding it to the event loop's queue. But you never await it, you just return it as any ordinary return value. Okay, now  the `ws_connect()` finishes and the event loop can choose to run any of the tasks, it chose to continue with `main` probably since it has been waiting on `ws_connect()`.

Okay, `main` prints D and returns. Now what?

There is some extra `await` in `asyncio.run` which gives `coro()` a chance to start - hence the printed *A* (but only after *D*) yet nothing forces `asyncio.run` to wait on `coro()` so when the coro yields back to the context loop through `async with`, the `run` finishes and program exits which leaves `coro()` unfinished.

If you add an extra `await asyncio.sleep(1)` after `print('D')`, the loop will again suspend `main` for at least some time and continue with `coro()` and that would print B had the URL been correct.

Actually, the context switching is little bit more complicated because ordinary `await` on a coroutine usually does not switches unless the execution really needs to block on IO or something `await asyncio.sleep(0)` or `yield`* guarantees a true context switch without the extra blocking.

*`yield` from inside `__await__` method.

**The lesson here is simple - never return awaitables from `async` methods, it leads to exactly this kind of mistake. Always use `return await` by default**, at worst you get runtime error in case the returned object is not actually awaitable(like `return await some_string`) and it can easily be spotted and fixed.

On the other hand, returning awaitables from ordinary functions is OK and makes it act like the function is asynchronous. Although one should be careful when mixing these two approaches. Personally, I prefer the first approach as it shifts the responsibility on the writer of the function, not the user which will be warned linters which usually do detect non-awaited corountine calls but not the returned awaitables. So another solution would to make `ws_connect` an ordinary function, then the `await` in `await ws_connect` would apply to the returned value(=the task), not the function itself.

Comment: One of the things I was not aware was the fact that "...the coro yields back to the context loop through `async with`..." By "context loop" do you mean the event loop? Why does it give its control back to the loop?(Is it because the `session` is an *awaitable* object?)

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant the event loop. It is due to how the async context managers work, they too have a pair of `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` **async** methods which are awaited. See [PEP 492 async with syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-syntax). You can see there `VAR = await aenter(mgr)` which can make a context switch depending on how `__aenter__` is implemented. Digging into `aiohttp` , it goes deep but there is a blocking await in `aiohttp/client.py:754` making the actual request to the URL which is a blocking IO call because it surely uses the sockets underneath.

Comment: @koyamashinji You can check most of the event loop for yourself using a debugger like `pdb` but it's not a very readable code and some of async stuff is hidden behind the syntactic sugar similar to `async with`

Comment: The deeper I go into the code, the lower the level gets and gosh it's so tough to understand! Anyways thank you for the helpful answers&comments, Ill look into it more.

Comment: @koyamashinji Yea, it's not meant for us mere mortals ;) The point is that you never awaited the coroutine and it did not get enough chances to finish before the program exited. Although async approach is a cooperative multitasking - you control where the functions are interrupted, their scheduling is still nondeterministic and cannot be relied upon.